# XAML ListBox - How to change style of last item only?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, .net-4.0, listbox

I have a `RadDataBoundListBox` (from Telerik) that represents the items of a List. Each item is separated by a bottom line `x:Name="ItemSeparatorBorder"`. The ListBox itself has a header and a footer containing a line too (`x:Name="ListTopBorder"`and `x:Name="ListBottomBorder"`). Now I need a way to **disable the line** (`x:Name="ItemSeparatorBorder"`) of the **last item** in this ListBox.

I thought about some `Visibility` binding to `x:Name="ItemSeparatorBorder"` with a `Converter` that matches the index of the current item to the total count of the ListBox. But I don't know how to implement it and I can't find any good sample.

The code should work on Windows Phone 8.0 / .NET 4.0.

This is my code so far:

```
    <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox
        x:Name="ListBox"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

        <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ListHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="30">
                    <Border
                        x:Name="ListTopBorder"
                        Height="1" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        Background="Blue"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ListHeaderTemplate>

        <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <controls:ListItem Margin="30,10,0,10">/>

                    <Border 
                        x:Name="ItemSeparatorBorder"
                        Grid.Row="1" 
                        Height="1" 
                        Background="Blue" 
                        Margin="30,0,0,0"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ListFooterTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="30">
                    <Border
                        x:Name="ListBottomBorder"
                        Height="1" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Background="Blue"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ListFooterTemplate>

    </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
```

How can I hide the Border of the last item?

To make it more clear, I want to remove the last blue line here:
[image]

Comment: it's the border of the `Listbox` is it?

Comment: No, I want to hide the `x:Name="ItemSeparatorBorder"` from the last item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use an IValueConverter that gets a reference to the items collection.  Make a converter that inherits `DependencyObject`, and give it a property for the source list.  Then you can check the current item index:

```
public class ItemToVisibilityConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public IList Items
    {
        get { return (IList )GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(IList), typeof(ItemToVisibilityConverter), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool hide = Items != null 
            && value != null 
            && Items.IndexOf(value) == Items.Count - 1;
        return (hide ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException;
    }
}
```

The put a converter instance in the control's resources:

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox
        x:Name="ListBox"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:ItemToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ItemToVisibilityConverter"
                    Items="{Binding Items}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.Resources>

    ...
</telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
```

Finally, in the "ItemTemplate", bind to the current item using the converter:

```
<Border x:Name="ItemSeparatorBorder"
        Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ItemToVisibilityConverter}}"
        ... />
```

Comment: If I run your code, `Items` in the `Convert` method is always `null`. And is there some way to use a `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`? When using a `ObservableCollection` the `Count` of the `Items`will be equal to the items index for each item.